# Run console application from html page with javascript or java?

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet, exe

Is there a way to run a user specified console application from an html page using Javascript or Java, a popup should come to verify the user wants to run the exe,? I would like to interact with the console application through its stdin and read out its stdout and do computations based on that and show the result on the html page.

The application is a Windows exe so I'm looking for solutions that work under Windows and only for  the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer.

Answers to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216024/java-applet-run-native-code-from-browser) on Stackoverflow suggests that signed java applets can solve this problem though I have not verified that the approach will even work and if it works will it work for the latest Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer. I was hoping there would be a solution with just Javascript and not requiring Java.

Comment: Absolutely not possible with Javascript. I don't know about Java so I won't post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks God it is impossible. Otherwise it would be a security breach.